# How to highlight android setting app menu item?

Tags: android, settings

When apps need to ask users to grant permissions through the settings app, it can be difficult for some users to figure out how to do it.

I came across this app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.treydev.pns

See this video showing it: https://youtu.be/eHXBc5Mmsqs

Somehow that app is able to highlight menu items within the settings app to guide the user through the process of granting permissions/adjusting settings, and it does so without asking for the accessibility service or any other permission first.

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Any luck finding a solution?

Comment: @Royz it takes advantage of bundle values within an intent and standard behavior for shared preference settings I believe.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you have any suggestions where can i find documentation or examples for that? A keyword would also be enough

Comment: I dug through android source code.  Keywords are intent bundle shared preference.

Comment: This has been answered here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/63214655/13957157