# Android: Highlight menu item in draw over other apps settings

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-permissions, android-settings

Starting from Android 11, using Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION will ignore the package name, and instead will show a list of all apps that can have this permission. So you have to navigate and find your app to enable/disable the permission.

There is a way to highlight the specific app you want in the list instead of having to search for it through all the apps. [Like this.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eHXBc5Mmsqs)

Following something similar to this: [Highlighting a menu item in system settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62979001/highlighting-a-menu-item-in-system-settings)
I want to make the same but for the "Draw over other apps" setting. (Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION)

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63214655/4720433), there are undocumented features of Android that can be used.

I want to know if something similar to what I am trying to achieve is possible and how?
Thanks in advance!